# Image in Widget not appearing on device but working fine on Emulator. How to fix?

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-imageview

I made a widget which reads an image from internal storage and displays it in an ImageView. It is working fine on the emulator (Android 2.3.3. API Level 10) but when I run it on my device (Droid Razr Android 2.3.6), it does not display the image. The widget is there on the screen but its just blank. Other parts of the widget are working fine like the Configuration Activity etc. Only the image is not appearing. What could be wrong ?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What you probably want to do is share any relevant code and/or research into the problem you've already done. That way folks will have a better idea of what's going on in your code.

Comment: I found out where I was going wrong. Anyways, will keep in mind to post some code in the future.

Comment: In that case, add an answer to your own question so folks will know how you solved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I fixed it. In my Storage class through which I store and read images from internal memory, there is a function that takes the **fileName** as a parameter. Now this **fileName** was to be used when making the final call to store it. Instead, I had written **"fileName"**. So there was only one file in the storage named **fileName**. This led to problems when reading from the storage using the actual fileName.

Answer (score 0):

I have two suggestions of what could be wrong:

- Your file may not be where specified on your device
- You may not have read permission for the file; try issuing `chmod a+r yourfile` in an adb shell

Comment: I changed the method by which it displays the image. Using RemoteView, I setup the ImageView bitmap from the Configuration Activity instead of widget reading the image from storage. Still same problem. Works on emulator but not on device.